# How many zeros do $z^n = a e^{-z-1}$ have inside the unit disk for $|a| < 1$? What are their multiplicities?

Tags: complex-analysis

> How many zeros do $z^n = a e^{-z-1}$ have inside the unit disk for
>   $|a| < 1$? What are their multiplicities?

The first question seems to be easy, since by Rouche's theorem $z^n - ae^{-z-1}$ should have the same zeros as $z^n$. So it should have $n$ zeros inside the unit disk. But what are their multiplicities?

Comment: Hint: If $z_0$ is at least double, $f(z_0) = f'(z_0) = 0$. Hence, you should derive the function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $a=0$ then obviously $z=0$ has multiplicity $n$.

For $a\neq 0$, a root has multiplicity >1 iff $z^n-ae^{-z-1}$ and $nz^{n-1}+ae^{-z-1}$ would both vanish (and for multiplicity 3 or above, $n(n-1)z^{n-2}-ae^{-z-1}$ would also vanish, etc.), but that means $z^n+nz^{n-1}=0$ (adding the two equations).  Clearly $z=0$ can't be a root, and the only other possibility is $z=-n$ which lies outside the disc.

Comment: Why $z=-n^{-1}$? No, it  would be $z=-n$, which is of course not a root. Also $z=0$ has to be checked.